# issue with width in IE 9 while it works fine in chrome , IE 7 & 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, width

JSFIddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cGadk/

in **Chrome** and **IE 7 & 8**

[image: Chrome view]

in **IE9**

[image: IE9 view]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="column">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">7</a>
    <a href="#">8</a>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <a href="#">9</a>
    <a href="#">10</a>
    <a href="#">11</a>
    <a href="#">12</a>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <a href="#">13</a>
    <a href="#">14</a>
    <a href="#">15</a>
    <a href="#">16</a>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <a href="#">13</a>
    <a href="#">14</a>
    <a href="#">15</a>
    <a href="#">16</a>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <a href="#">17</a>
    <a href="#">18</a>
    <a href="#">19</a>
    <a href="#">10</a>
</div>
```

​

**CSS**

```
a{
font-size:13px;
font-family : arial;
display : block;
border:1px solid black;
padding : 5px;
}

.column{
    float:left;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
   var width = 0;

   $('.column').each(function(i, el){
    width += $(el).width();
   });

    $('.container').width(width);
})(jQuery);
```

​

Comment: yes. i know that, but i want to its work in ie 9

Comment: I would consider applying the universal selector * rule to reset all margins, paddings, borders, etc for all browsers.

Comment: If all else fails, you can force IE8 mode.

Comment: Why not using CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/N6CvV/

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with `.container` div. It is too small for IE9.

If you change your JS code from `$('.container').width(width);` to `$('.container').width(width+10);` it will look right.

**EDIT**

I found nice explanation of this problem and some potential fixes in [IE9 rendering CSS tables differently than Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7997432/1916110) question.

Comment: Why is it so? Why does it fail in IE9 only?

Comment: It is a very good question. I had that problem many times before. However, did not manage to come up with any elegant solution. And the workaround, which I have proposed, worked perfectly fine. So did not spend much time to get to the bottom of the issue.